# How to populate list in each row of a column in lua script

Tags: lua

For a standard list in a single cell I simply enter

```
__iVarname = {"1 /apple", "2 /banana", "3 /orange"}
```

in a lua script to get a list of 3 fruits in the cell. Now if that variable is a column of n rows

```
__IVarname = {"1 /apple", "2 /banana", "3 /orange"}
```

the list doesn't populate in each cell.
I tried for loop 0 to n

```
for i =0,40 do
__IVarname = {"1 /apple", "2 /banana", "3 /orange"}
end
```

but it didn't work correctly. I am new to lua script so I do not know the syntax for populating list/combobox in an array and coudn't find any during my search.

Comment: there are no rows, columns and comboboxes in Lua. you just need to learn how to populate a Lua table. this is very basic knowledge that should be obtained through reading the manual or any beginners tutorial or book

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not quite sure what is `__iVarname`, what a strange name for a variable, but I can explain what is your code doing:

```
for i =0,40 do
__IVarname = {"1 /apple", "2 /banana", "3 /orange"}
end
```

In this loop, `__IVarname` will be set to the value `{"1 /apple", "2 /banana", "3 /orange"}`. And this will happen 41 times. At the end of the loop, the value of `__IVarname` is `{"1 /apple", "2 /banana", "3 /orange"}`.

I think what you want to do is to have a table containing all the values. For the reasons which are yours, you want to populate your list with the same value. In `Lua`, one could write the following code:

```
__IVarname = {} -- create a new table
for i=1,40 do
  __IVarname[i] = {"1 /apple", "2 /banana", "3 /orange"}
end
```

There is also an additional possible syntax for appending new items at the end of a table, `#__IVarname` returning the number of elements in the `table`:

```
__IVarname = {} -- create a new table
for i=1,40 do
  __IVarname[#__IVarname+1] = {"1 /apple", "2 /banana", "3 /orange"}
end
```